# Hyperedit, php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is not a particular php question, but it is to do with accesing php by using mysql when the file is not hosted on the same domain.

For example, im using hyperedit, the php  coding tool that allows you to display the results of php in realtime as you code.

However when i try and type my mysql code in, that i know works(i tested it using my servers built in php/html etc creator) i get a error:

> Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://myservername.servername.com

Its definitely not my code, i think instead it is something to do with the fact that the file is not being hosted on the server? I have only tried it in hyperedit but i think the same would occur in other programs too.

I know its not specifically php or coding related, but i thought this is the best place to ask!
If anyone could help me it would be great!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Did you specify your database information correctly? Connection Refused typically means that the hostname, database name, username or password is incorrect or that the remote server is down.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply! Yes i am sure the information is correct as i use the exact same code on my server by just putting it in a php file. When i edit it/ use the code using my servers tools, its fine. However when i try and use php applications like Hyperedit it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your local development machine does not have access to the mysql server in question.

If this is a shared account, you may be able to grant access to your remote machine's IP/hostname through cPanel.  If you have direct access to the remote box through the cli, you can do it via a sql GRANT command, like so:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO myusername@'my_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

Otherwise, it may be locked down in a shared environment where only machines on the local subnet can access the mysql server (cough, GoDady, cough).

So there's no real answer.  Either you have the privileges to give your remote machine access, or you don't.  If you don't, consider using another host that does allow you to do what you need.

Comment: Ahh i thought it was something to do with this! I don't think my host supports it then, its ipage do you know if they do or not? Thanks very much for your fast response!

Comment: A cursory glance of their site seems to indicate that they do not allow you to add users that are not local.